# Duplicate Objects detected for Instance X of Type Y

Tags: structuremap

I'm getting the following exception from structure map -  "Duplicate Objects detected for Instance d54e25dc-d19c-4d70-99d1-56bd2502d203 of Type ..."

The stack trace is:

```
at StructureMap.InstanceCache.Set(Type pluginType, Instance Instance, Object result) in c:\code\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\InstanceCache.cs:line 60
at StructureMap.BuildSession.CreateInstance(Type pluginType, Instance instance) in c:\code\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\BuildSession.cs:line 159
at StructureMap.BuildSession.<>c_DisplayClass3.<.ctor>b_1() in c:\code\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\BuildSession.cs:line 34
at StructureMap.BuildSession.CreateInstance(Type pluginType) in c:\code\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\BuildSession.cs:line 192
at StructureMap.BuildSession.GetInstance[T]() in c:\code\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\BuildSession.cs:line 78
```

This exception happens only from time to time and is very difficult to reproduce.

What I've found out so far:

- Calling `ObjectFactory.Container.GetInstance(type)` will create a new `BuildSession` with a new non-static cache.
- The call will reach `BuildSession.CreateInstance(Type pluginType, Instance instance)` and no instance is in the cache yet. (https://github.com/structuremap/structuremap/blob/master/Source/StructureMap/BuildSession.cs#L149-166)
- Now we'll go on to `_builder.Resolve(pluginType, instance, this);`
- Somewhere during `Resolve()` the object will get into the cache and later in `CreateInstance` we're saving it into the cache once again, receiving the exception.

That object is configured with *Singleton* lifecycle. The application is WCF service hosted in IIS.

Any help with finding the cause is appreciated.